# Configuring dma Unix

Tags: linux, docker, opencpu

I am trying to install OpenCPU inside a docker container. After some steps, this message appears:

[image]

I am quite new to Linux because I am a Windows user. I found nothing on my research so I am asking this question.

Can I just choose some random mail here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We just use our domain name, but don't use this functionality at all. What i did want to mention, in case anyone else runs into problems with this, you can disable the interactive part in docker by setting `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive`.